# Which is the canonical Nvidia drivers question for 13.04?

Tags: discussion

we seem to have a bunch of similar Nvidia questions with the same problem, here are some possible candidates for a canonical question:

- [Install NVIDIA Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286767/install-nvidia-drivers)
- [Is it safe to install the Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285074/is-it-safe-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-13-04)

Any other candidates so we can start to clean them up?

Answer (score 1):

This is one I have been working on since January with 13.04. I happened to get lucky and have a friend to test the Ati part on, so I can say I have tested a couple of Nvidia, Ati and Intel video cards with it: [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-a-video-card-nvidia-ati-or-intel)

And if you do not think is inappropriate I would like to mention the following links about other questions:

- Broadcom wireless cards: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
- General Development Issues: [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)
- Upgrading to 13.04: [How do I upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279620/how-do-i-upgrade-from-12-10-to-13-04/279626#279626)
- Ubuntu Touch: [What is Ubuntu Touch (Ubuntu for Phones)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235317/what-is-ubuntu-touch-ubuntu-for-phones-and-how-to-get-it)

This get a lot of duplicates over time.

There are also some like this one:

[Is Ubuntu totally functional on Intel Extreme DZ77GA hardware?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258729/is-ubuntu-totally-functional-on-intel-extreme-dz77ga-hardware)

That are starting to appear more often. They are typically related to a "Does ubuntu work in this type of hardware". So a more canonical answer can be created using any of the ones that exist. Maybe pointing them to an Ubuntu site that covers hardware testing or some guidance over testing that particular hardware with a Live installed.

Comment: Where do we draw the line between "how do I solve x" and "give me all the solutions for x"? That answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-install-a-video-card-nvidia-ati-or-intel fits better a wiki page and is not aimed at Ask Ubuntu. A user reading it for the first time will be just more confused than before he did.

Comment: Besides, changing the title kinda looses the focus on the question (which has nothing to do with the body of the question), it actually makes it off spec for Ask Ubuntu...

Comment: I don't get this answer, I'm talking about finding out which nvidia question to use for 13.04.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Was referring to other questions that also need the same solution as the Nvidia one.